# PHP function to download and overwrite the previews downloaded file

Tags: php, download, zip

I am using the following code to download an archived csv file and uncompress it:

```
$url="http://www.some.zip";
$target = 'data-' . md5(microtime()) . '.zip';

function download($src, $dst) {
        $f = fopen($src, 'rb');
        $o = fopen($dst, 'wb');
        while (!feof($f)) {
            if (fwrite($o, fread($f, 2048)) === FALSE) {
                   return 1;
            }
        }
        fclose($f);
        fclose($o);
        return 0;
}

download($url,$target);

if ( file_exists($target) ){
    echo "Download Successuful <br />";
    $arc = new ZipArchive;
    if (true !== $arc->open($target)) {
        echo "Unzipping Failed <br />";
    }else {
        file_put_contents($out, $arc->getFromIndex(0));
        echo "Unzipping Successuful <br />";
        fclose($handle);
    }
}else {
     echo "Download Failed <br />";
}
```

However, on a second run, it does't do anything and I would like to overwrite the initial file with the newer file. (the CSV File)

How should I do that? The solution should take about the same time as the first download!

Comment: Why should it do anything? you're creating the file with a micros-second timestamp. The first time you run it, it will be `data-1234567890`, then the next time you'll be looking for `data-345678912`. You'll never be able to find the previous file, because you only ever look for the "now" timestamp.

Comment: Sorry about that, now it has to be named "filename.zip", respectively, "filename.csv"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to first check if the file exists, then remove it.

```
function download($src, $dst) {
    if(file_exists($dst)) unlink($dst);
    $f = fopen($src, 'rb');
    $o = fopen($dst, 'wb');
    while (!feof($f)) {
        if (fwrite($o, fread($f, 2048)) === FALSE) {
               return 1;
        }
    }
    fclose($f);
    fclose($o);
    return 0;
```

}